# Can i use Django Admin for the user interface when there will only be 2-3 users?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-admin-filters

i am working on a project where i am creating a project management webapp for a small team (4-5 users). They will use it mainly for data management (CRUD operations for projects, resources, work hours, budgets etc.) and creating reports.

For the CRUD part of the application i want to use Django Admin. Only 2-3 users will apply CRUD operations on the data. So i want to call them "administrators" and use the built-in Admin app because it literally has all the functionalities i need.
It will save a lot of time and costs which is very important for this project

I read that Admin is only meant for site administrators and this is not recommended. My question is: With this use case for the application can i use a Django admin app as a part of the User interface?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean normal users can perform CRUD operations to admin site?

Comment: You can manage restrictions for specific group of users with built-in [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization), allowing them to read/change/delete data

Comment: @SunderamDubey Yes, because there are only a few users of the app i think it wouldn't be an issue.. 
But on other websites i read that admin is meant for the website developers and not for application users

Comment: @Ersain Thanks that's true, so do you think it can be used by the end-users of the application? I read that it is meant for the website developers

Comment: Assuming that the admin page will be used by few users, it's completely fine